# Load JSON file in teradata

Tags: json, vba, teradata

I want to know how I can manage to load JSON file in Teradata SQL assistant.
Do you have any tips?
Because i have to import JSON file in TERADATA.

Comment: Is [this site](https://docs.teradata.com/reader/hPLK~VSHqqKFSCfWKML4gA/oUiEuR3_uv9IWjyPVjgehQ) not exactly what you are looking for?

Comment: It's a part of the answer but i need a script in order to automate the process.

Comment: That would be the "Loading JSON Data Using Load Utilities" section on that site where it gives you examples of how to load JSON using TPT with links to the TPT user guide for more in-depth. You'll have to build a TPT script to point to the file and load into your target table.